# no process listening on port 8080 but shows already in use

Tags: java, spring-boot

I try to start a Spring boot project. It worked fine originally, but after I restart my computer for some reason, I keep getting the messages "Port xxxx was already in use".

And Even if I change the port, I still get this error. I'm pretty sure I have no process in use.
Though it might be solved when I restart my computer, I was still wondering the problem.

Comment: If you are on macOS (and maybe Linux too) you can use the following command to find what process is using a port: `lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN | grep <port-number>`

Comment: Does restarting solve it? Your question isn't clear on that point.